# Summing a range based on whether other non-contiguous cells contain text or numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumproduct

I am trying to add a range of numbers only if the corresponding cells contain numerical values.

I am working on a grade tracking document where every assignment contains a different weighting. When students do not write the test an NA is entered. I would like to check which cells contain numerical values and add the corresponding weightings.

[image: Grades]

In the image above, the '%' column is automatically calculated and I would like this new formula to seek information from the 'Mark'column.

I tried this formula but it doesn't exclude NA and I am unsure how to include ISNUMBER to use this instead, Or maybe there is something else entirely I should be trying.

SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},B31,F31,J31,N31,R31,V31,Z31,AD31)>0),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8},L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10,L11,L12))

L5 to L12 contain the weightings I would like added. L5 corresponds to B31, L6 to F31 and so on...

I would like to check if B31,F31,J31,N31,R31,V31,Z31,AD31 are numerical values and then add the corresponding cells in Column L.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I have created a sample sheet showing what I am trying to do with a further explanation written beneath it. Thank you so much for your assistance. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-rSzbt0U-ZHXD7rNHOC5Cm0ulBbRqx90fsJ5aZvnR6k/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SUMPRODUCT because you need to multiply L5*B31,L6*F31.... and sum the result??
If that's so, you can use it like this:

> =sumproduct(L5:L12,arrayformula(iferror({B31;F31;J31;N31;R31;V31;Z31;AD31},0)))

It it's a text or an error (that's why the arrayformula and iferror) it will be considered as "0". If "NA" is not an error and there aren't any chances of having one you can just use:

> =sumproduct(L5:L12,{B31;F31;J31;N31;R31;V31;Z31;AD31})

---

Considering your given sample, you could divide this result by a sumif of the total marks of the tests the student actually took. With your new ranges that would be:

> =sumproduct($H$4:$H$8,{C15;E15;G15;I15;K15})/sumif({C15;E15;G15;I15;K15},">0",$H$4:$H$8)

Or with the previous ones:

> =sumproduct($L$5:$L$12,{B31;F31;J31;N31;R31;V31;Z31;AD31}/SUMIF({B31;F31;J31;N31;R31;V31;Z31;AD31},">0",$L$5:$L$12)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wjvlK74nbUM7NfvG23fQL_T6fin6FL6YpYAxjsMV9sk/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I would like the text or errors to be excluded rather than counted as zero since counting as zero lowers the overall grade. What I would like is to find a new total weighting for those students who miss a test. So instead of the total weighting being 1, it would be 0.85 for example. So I am looking for a formula that checks if a mark exists in row 31 and then excludes the corresponding weighting in column L and sums the rest of the weightings. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry, I'm really trying to figure out the procedure, but don't get it. Could you share a sample calculation with and without NA to understand the difference and how should the final result change. If you have a spreadsheet, it would be great, with one example of perfect assistance and one without (calculated "by hand" obviously, but to understand the procedure). Thanks

Comment: I am so sorry, I have created a sample sheet showing what I am trying to do with a further explanation written beneath it. Thank you so much for your assistance. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-rSzbt0U-ZHXD7rNHOC5Cm0ulBbRqx90fsJ5aZvnR6k/edit#gid=0

Comment: Ahhh, OK, now I think I see it. What if that Sumproduct you divide it by a Sumif according to if there's a number in the mark. In your example sheet, that would be in Student 1: =sumproduct($H$4:$H$8,{C15;E15;G15;I15;K15})/sumif({C15;E15;G15;I15;K15},">0",$H$4:$H$8) . I'll add an edit and link in my answer

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I appreciate the assistance.